# Elementary not booting from usb

Tags: boot, usb-drive

[image]Im trying to boot form usb but keep getting a failed message! Can anyone help . 
I had almost finished installation previously but my laptop died in the later stages, is this the cause?

Comment: if someone stumble on this question, do try to disable Secure Boot based from answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/25758/24823)

Answer (score 0):

First, verify your ISO image (check the hash of the image as described [here](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download))
Flash the elementaryOS iso again on another USB (if possible).

If that doesn't help, next step is to boot into live session, go to the `/boot/efi` and rename `grubx64.efi` to `mmx64.efi` as answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found).

Another solution I found on [this forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/something-has-gone-seriously-wrong-import_mok_state-failed-4175665926/), where he used 2 USB keys to boot from one and install from another.

Answer (score 0):

Make Elementary OS Bootable USB drive by:
Steps

1. Download Etcher / Balena Etcher
2. Get the Elementary OS ISO files
3. Run Etcher and add ISO image
4. Bootable Elementary OS USB drive is ready