# Cant install elementary, Security Violation

Tags: install

I really want to try out elementary os. I made a bootable USB on both Rufus and etcher. Both give me the same results. I get a blue screen saying Verification failed: (0x1A) Security Violation. I have turned off secure boot. If I press ok I see on the lower left side flash quickly:

Failed to load image: Security Policy Violation
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found

Anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Hmmm, is it possible that the download was corrupted? Were you able to check the SHA-256 sum of the file as documented here: https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium

Answer (score 2):

You will need to disable 'Secure Boot' in your machine's BIOS settings.

Comment: +1 This done it. I have try rename the grub64.efi to mmx64.efi but when boot from usb, it will show error that grub64.efi not found. Trying rename back mmx64 tu grub64 and disable from bios under Security -> Secured Boot Menu, the usb boot without any error.